# How do you access nested object information with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I've got two models connected through a ManyToManyField that links projects together with users, as such:

```
class Project(Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('active', 'Active'),
        ('archived','Archived'),
    )

    name = CharField(max_length=50)
    members = ManyToManyField("accounts.User", through='ProjectUser')
    organization = ForeignKey(Organization, related_name="organizations", on_delete=CASCADE, verbose_name="Team")
    status = CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='active')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



    class Meta:
        db_table = 'project'
        ordering = ('organization', 'name')
        unique_together = ('name', 'organization',) 


class ProjectUser(Model):
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('member', 'Member'),
        ('admin','Admin'),
    )
    user = ForeignKey("accounts.User", on_delete=CASCADE)
    project = ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=CASCADE)
    user_hour_cost = DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    role = CharField(max_length=10, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default='member')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'projectuser'
        ordering = ('user',)
        unique_together = ('project', 'user',)
```

and a ProjectSerializer that looks like this:

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ["name", "organization", "members"]
```

I wish to extract data about the users when using the `ProjectSerializer` (e.g get the username, email, first name, last name from the `User` model). All I get back with this serializer is

```
{
    "name": "Project X/Y",
    "organization": 1,
    "members": [
        2,
        1
    ]
}
```

Is there a way for me to traverse the information on the `members` so my template can use it? E.g members[0].username?

I can't just use `depth = 1` because that returns data directly from `User` model, but ignores the fields on the `ProjectUser` model

I'm looking for something along the lines of

```
{
    "name": "Project X/Y AB",
    "organization": 1,
    "projectusers": [
        {
            "user": ["id": 1, "username": "foo", "first_name": "joey"],
            "project": 1,
            "user_hour_cost": "550.00",
            "role": "admin"
        },
        {
            "user": ["id": 2, "username": "hellboy", "first_name": "erik"],
            "project": 1,
            "user_hour_cost": "190.00",
            "role": "member"
        }
    ]
}
```

Doesn't necessarily have to look just like this - but I need for my frontend to receive information about the user that sits on the `User` table in my db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved it by just nesting another serialized object inside `ProjectUser`

User Serializer

```
from accounts.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "first_name", "email")
```

and then

```
from .models import Project
from .models import ProjectUser
from accounts.serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers



class ProjectUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectUser
        fields = ("user", "user_hour_cost", "role")


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    projectusers = ProjectUserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ["name", "organization", "projectusers"]
```

Which returned

```
{
    "name": "Project XXAA",
    "organization": 1,
    "projectusers": [
        {
            "user": {
                "username": "Google",
                "first_name": "Chrome",
                "email": "google@chrome.com"
            },
            "user_hour_cost": "550.00",
            "role": "admin"
        },
        {
            "user": {
                "username": "Mozilla",
                "first_name": "Joey",
                "email": "mozilla@firefox.com"
            },
            "user_hour_cost": "190.00",
            "role": "member"
        }
    ]
}
```

Good enough to work with!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to specify your own serializer for the (project)users. This is covered more in depth in the official [DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

```py
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    members = MemberSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ["name", "organization", "members"]
```

and define your `Member` and `User` Serializer:

```py
class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectMember
        fields = ["user ", "...", "role "]

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["id", "username", "first_name", "..."]
```

But beware that making such a construct writeable is tricky. You would probably have to overwrite your Serializers `create()` methods to implement this. See [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) for more details.

Comment: If you did not use nested serializers, maybe you could elaborate on how you did it?

Comment: I did - check my post in "Answer"

Comment: so you did exactly what my answer suggested?

Comment: Yeah looks like it - sorry but I didn't read your suggested answer before posting my answer

Comment: then please accept one of those answers, as the problem is obviously solved.